# unexpected T_IF, if statement in array

Tags: php

I can't figure out why I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 6.

```
 $sf = array ( 

            "name" => $firstname . ' ' . $lastname,
            "email" => $email,
            "address" => $shipping_address_1 . if(!empty($shipping_address_2 )) { echo ", " . $shipping_address_2 }
            );
            print_r($sf);
```

I want to check if $shipping_address_2 is not empty, and if it's not, then display it.

Comment: Because the `if` statement is invalid there. Statements cannot be used inside expressions (apart from expression statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 "address" => $shipping_address_1 . if(!empty($shipping_address_2 )) { echo ", " . $shipping_address_2 }
```

With

```
"address" => $shipping_address_1 . (empty($shipping_address_2) ? null :  ", " . $shipping_address_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your code is wrong. You cannot put an `if` statement inside the array initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure, but you should be able to use a ternary operator...

```
"address" => $shipping_address_1 . 
    (!empty($shipping_address_2 )) ? 
        ", " . $shipping_address_2 : // This gets executed if condition is true
        ""    // This gets executed if the condition is false
```

Comment: Nitpick: It's *a* ternary operator and *the conditional* operator ;)

Comment: @Felix wow, never even heard the distinction before.  Updated and thanks :)

Comment: I didn't know that either for a long time ;)

Comment: But since there is often only one ternary operator in programming languages, it can also be THE ternary operator.